# How to create a file carrier Android app?

Tags: android, file, apk, extract

I want to create a simple Android app that carries files that are imported in it and those files can be readable accessible and intractable by the user that installs the app

I can import files into assets and raw folder of android apps but i don't know how to make them accessable for the user
There must be a way to make the app manually ore automatically extract the files into internal storage of the users phone
Then they can even uninstall the app because all files are in their phone .

Comment: Assets is the wrong approach. Assets can only be changed at compile-time. The user can not change assets. And "carrier" is the wrong term, in the context of Android this is the mobile network operator company.

Comment: So what do you recommend?

Comment: First make a clear description of the app you want to develop and then develop small test apps for testing each required feature.